# invalid ELF header - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/nio4r-2.5.9/lib/nio4r_ext.so (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am not sure how to resolve this, cannot find information online to help, however I have found that is it to do with the nio4r gem but nothing much else. Please help and let me know what I can do, any more information. I am using fedora, linux.

```
   [ben@localhost-live hello_app]$ rails s
    => Booting Puma
    => Rails 7.0.4.3 application starting in development 
    => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
    Puma starting in single mode...
    * Puma version: 5.6.5 (ruby 3.2.1-p31) ("Birdie's Version")
    *  Min threads: 5
    *  Max threads: 5
    *  Environment: development
    *          PID: 33779
    * Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
    * Listening on http://[::1]:3000
    Exiting
    <internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/nio4r-2.5.9/lib/nio4r_ext.so: invalid ELF header - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/nio4r-2.5.9/lib/nio4r_ext.so (LoadError)
        from <internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/nio4r-2.5.9/lib/nio.rb:42:in `<main>'
        from <internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/reactor.rb:24:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/server.rb:244:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/server.rb:244:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/single.rb:53:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/launcher.rb:193:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:72:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:327:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:38:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from <internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    [ben@localhost-live hello_app]$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem comes up when the native extensions have been compiled improperly. You need to recompile the nio4r gem's native extensions. There are many, many possible causes of the issue:

1. You compiled the extensions by passing in invalid arguments (for example, telling it to compile for the wrong architecture)
2. You compiled the extensions on another operating system and then moved them manually to this system
3. You compiled the extensions in the past, then did a major system upgrade or operating system change, then attempted to continue using the previously compiled extensions

There are other possible causes as well but the most straightforward solution is to recompile the extensions:

```bash
bundle pristine nio4r
```

If you continue to have the problem then ensure that your bundler platform is `ruby` and only `ruby`:

```bash
bundle config force_ruby_platform true
```

This will have the following effect:

> Ignore the current machine's platform and install only `ruby` platform gems. As a result, gems with native extensions will be compiled from source.

Then retry `bundle pristine nio4r` to force recompilation.